# passenger-nginx-module Cannot find the `curl-config` command

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

Can anyone please help me with this:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Now it shows this:
    Checking for required software...

```
 * Checking for Curl development headers with SSL support...
      Found: no
      Error: Cannot find the `curl-config` command.
Installation instructions for required software

 * To install Curl development headers with SSL support:
   Please run apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev or libcurl4-gnutls-dev, whichever you prefer.
```

Now when i am trying to install

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

The main issue:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to run 'apt-get update' first in order to update your package database.

Comment: You didn't say whether you ran apt-get update. I was going to suggest alternatives to investigate, but you downmodded me for trying to help you so you're on your own now.